# future is not run even if get() is called

Tags: c++, c++11, asynchronous, future

I want to run some `system` calls in parallel, but even if I call `f1.get()` the coping in the lines below does not take place. What is wrong with this code?

```
auto f1 = std::async( system, string("cp a b").c_str() );
f1.get(); // there is still no file "b".
```

Note: I wrote `string(...).c_str()` because in my real code I'm using putting the argument together from different strings.

Comment: `string("cp a b").c_str()` will pass a dangling pointer to `system` when it is run.

Comment: On the other hand, string literals stay alive. `std::async( system, "cp a b")`

Comment: And the code seems to work. Perhaps there are a few problems with the way arguments to `system` are constructed.

Comment: Please, do not enter the solution inside your question, but post an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `std::string` containing your command is a temporary object and will only live until the end of the `std::async` call,
so by the time `system` is called, the pointer may refer to deleted memory, which may happen to work, or it might read `rm -rf / --no-preserve-root` - it's undefined behavior.

You need to ensure the string object lives long enough. In your example that is easy enough, but it's not always so if you're launching asynchronous operations.

C++11 lambda expressions give us a nice way store the string for exactly as long as we need it:

```
std::string command = "cp main.cpp b";

auto f1 = std::async(std::launch::async, 
    [command]{ // copy command into the closure
        std::system(command.c_str()); 
    }
);
```

Also, note that you didn't request the `async` launch policy, so your function may execute synchronously still.

Side note: You may want to consider using something like [POCO's `Process`](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Process.html) if you're launching external processes and want to capture output, exit status and so on.